# Can I use deviance to compare the fit of a model to different datasets?

Tags: r, residuals, nonlinear-regression, deviance, nls

I'm using `R`'s `nls` to fit different datasets to the same model. I've read that using R-squared is usually not correct for non-linear regressions, however, I'd like to be able to tell which fit is apparently better.

I don't plan to use the deviance (residual sum-of-squares) to choose or say which data is better, but a numeric parameter will come handy in order to help me optmize the algorithm which manipulates the data.

The datasets have the same order of magnitude, and visual inspection of the original vs fitted curves doesn't show much difference. However, I have values of e.g. ${dev_1 = 0.0240}$ vs ${dev_2 = 0.0072}$, which I think are considerably different.

So, can I suppose ${fit_2}$ was better than ${fit_1}$? If not, is there any other (relatively simple) way to compare this values?